# How to grep to extract the previous n characters from a file

Tags: grep, bioinformatics

I'm trying to extract some data from a file using `grep`.

The file is a DNA fasta file containing lines such as:

```
ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTAGT
```

I need to find every `TA` and the 20 characters before the `TA`

I'm currently trying: `grep -E -o ".{0,20}TA"`

But this produces output which gives the characters between `TA` strings - in the above line it gives - eg:

```
TCGATGCTGCTA
```

```
GCATCGTA
```

Which is the string between two `TA` occurrences,  where I want to get:

```
TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
```

```
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
```

Which contain instances of the search string.

Is there a way to do this in `grep`?

Comment: So your problem is, you want to get overlapping sequences, while `grep -o` just produces non-overlapping results?

Comment: `{0,20}TA` matches anywhere from 0 to 20 characters before `TA`.   Try `{20}`. 
  For example: `echo ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTAGT | grep -E -o '.{20}TA'`

Comment: if you don't need overlapping matches (i.e. matches that contain parts of the input that were previously matched), you could use `echo ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTAGT | perl -pe 's/(.{20}TA)/$1\n/g'` - that outputs `ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA` and `TGCTAGATGCTAGT`

Comment: If it is a fasta file, does it also contain sequence headers?

Comment: This works but youare right to think I need overlapping matches...the sed and awk solutions below work well - I ended up using mosvys solution - many thanks everyone - this was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

As you want overlapping strings, I'm afraid no tool can provide that by default. It is neccessary to loop over the input to find all overlapping occurences. The next problem is the greedy nature over regular expressions: You will not find the leading `ATCGTA`, if a `ATCGTAGCTA` can be found. This makes it more complicated to do the loop:

```
sed -E ':1
 h;s/(.*TA).*/\1/
 s/.{0,20}TA$/_&/
 s/.*_//p
 g;s/(.*)TA.*/\1/;t1
 d
```

is the first solution I can think of. The output for the example should contain all sequences you want:

```
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTA
ATCGTAGCTA
ATCGTA
```

Explained: It seems easier to start from the last match, so

- `h` save the buffer in the hold space for the next cycle
- `s/(.*TA).*/\1/` removes everything after the last `TA`
- `s/.{0,20}TA$/_&/` places an underscore as a marker at the start of the sequence you want to get
- `s/.*_//p` removes everything upto the marker and prints the sequence
- To prepare for the next cycle, `g` restores the saved pattern and `s/(.*)TA.*/\1/` removes the last `TA` and following, so it won't be found again
- finally `t1` starts over from `:1` while a sequence was found.
- `d` suppresses bogus output at the end

Answer (score 1):

There are only three sub-sequences in your given sequence that are 20 bases followed by `TA`.  These are all overlapping each other.  The `grep` utility can't be used to extract overlapping strings as there has to be multiple passes over line to find all sub-strings.

```
ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTAGT
----TA--TA------TA----------TA---TA-----TA--
                    01234567890123456789
             01234567890123456789
        01234567890123456789
```

These sequences may be found with the following `sed` script (written to be used with `sed -n`):

```sed
:again
s/\(.*.\{20\}TA\).*/\1/
h
s/.*\(.\{20\}TA\)/\1/p
g
s/TA$//
t again
```

1. The first command is a label, `again`, which we will use to process the next sub-sequence in a line of input.
2. The first substitution trims off all sequence after the last `TA`.
3. The `h` puts the trimmed sequence into the "hold space" (a temporary buffer in `sed`).
4. The second substitution finds the last sequence of 20 bases, followed by `TA` and prints it.
5. The `g` retrieves the previously stored sequence from the hold space (discarding the just printed sequence).
6. The third substitution removes the `TA` from the end of the string.
7. The `t` command jumps to the `again` label if the most recent substitution actually did anything.

Testing it:

```
$ sed -n -f script.sed file
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
```

If you add the single `sed` command `=` to the very top of the `sed` script, you will additionally get an indication of what input line produces what output.  The following is showing that with you data repeated on three lines:

```
$ sed -n -f script.sed file
1
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
2
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
3
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
```

Comment: @mosvy No worries. Yes, a Perl solution may well be many times faster for sure.

Comment: This is almost the solution of my answer, but it drops `TA` sequences with less than 20 chars before them. The expression `.{0,20}TA` from the question suggests that "upto" 20 characters before should be found, so `ATCGTA` and two other sequences are missing.

Comment: @Philippos Yes, I started writing it before seeing yours. I chose to go by the words in the question rather than the suggested code though, so I don't care about shorter sub-sequences. Rearranging it to support also the shorter sub-sequences would make it even more like yours, so I decided not to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a way to get overlapping matches with `grep -o` (I don't know of any, not even with `grep -Po`), but in the meanwhile you can use `awk`:

```
echo ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTAGT |
awk '{
   i=0; for(s=$0; j = index(s,"TA"); s = substr($0, i + 1))
            print ((i += j) > 20) ? substr($0, i - 20, 22) : substr($0, 1, i+1)
}'

ATCGTA
ATCGTAGCTA
ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTA
TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA
```

If you don't want the shorter matches from the beginning of the string, simplify it to:

```
echo ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTAGT |
awk '{
    i=0; for(s=$0; j = index(s,"TA"); s = substr($0, i + 1))
             if((i += j) > 20) print substr($0, i - 20, 22)
}'

TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA
```

---

The same thing in `perl`:

```
echo ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTAGT |
perl -nle 'print $-[0] > 20 ? substr $_, $-[0]-20, 22 : substr $_, 0, $+[0] while /TA/g'

ATCGTA
ATCGTAGCTA
ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTA
TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA


echo ATCGTAGCTAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTAGT |
perl -nle 'pos() -= 21, print $1 while /(.{20}TA)/g'

TAGCATCGTATCGATGCTGCTA
TCGTATCGATGCTGCTATGCTA
GATGCTGCTATGCTAGATGCTA
```

---

If using `mawk` (the default on debian-like) the `awk` version will be faster.

While fine for displaying `sed` mastery, any `sed` solution is bound to be many *orders of magnitude* slower that either `perl` or `awk`.