# Grep omits matchs in a paragraph with several occurence of a pattern

Tags: grep

I try to find in a paragraph all the expression of the form "word word word word the word word word word".

For this, I use the expression `grep -E -o '([^ ]+ ){4}the( [^ ]+){5}'`

But in this example `echo "word1 word2 word3 word4 the word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 the quoi écrire hihi haha the a b c d e" | grep -E -o '([^ ]+ ){4}the( [^ ]+){5}'`

I only get as results

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 the word5 word6 word7 word8 word9
quoi écrire hihi haha the a b c d e
```

But I would also want

```
word6 word7 word8 word9 the quoi écrire hihi haha the
```

Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: They overlap...

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I am trying to find a workaround.

Comment: `grep` can't handle overlapping matches. There is no standard tool that does this, so it would require either a Perl-like regular expression with negative lookaheads (possibly), or some explicit looping in either `sed` or `awk` or some larger language (Perl/Python).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't thought about searching a workaround with the keywork overlapping. Now I think I can handle this with some research.

Comment: Fetching overlapping matches is discussed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538249/364705 , maybe you can adapt one of the answers there.

Comment: Try something like: `... | perl -nE 'say "$1$3" while /((\S+ ){4}the)(?=(( \S+){5}))/g'`

Comment: This turned out to work. Maybe the only thing I don't understand is the `$3`. What does it stand for?

Comment: I got it by myself. It is the first time I encounter capturing groups, so sorry for the bother. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to do the grepping iteratively, removing the first matched portion each time:

```sh
string="word1 word2 word3 word4 the word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 the quoi écrire hihi haha the a b c d e"

copy=$string
while m=$(grep -Eo '([^ ]+ ){4}the( [^ ]+){5}' <<<"$copy"); do
    echo "$m" | head -1    # print just the first one
    copy=${copy#* the }    # remove up to and including the _first_ " the "
done
```

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 the word5 word6 word7 word8 word9
word6 word7 word8 word9 the quoi écrire hihi haha the
quoi écrire hihi haha the a b c d e
```

Or, use bash's builtin regex support, which means you don't need to parse any `grep` output to print the first match:

```sh
copy=$string
# the pattern is *unquoted*
while [[ $copy =~ ([^ ]+ ){4}the( [^ ]+){5} ]]; do
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    copy=${copy#* the }
done
```